# How to save RDD in Spark existing in different slave machines to different S3 location

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr

I want to divide a large file which exists in S3 into multiple chunks.

So I am trying to solve this problem by reading the file into Spark running on Amazon EMR with number of instances (say 10 for example).

This would create approx 10 partitions of RDDs which are stored in individual slave nodes.

While saving the files (rdd.saveAsTextfile(s3-path)), how can I Specify separate path for individual RDD stored in different nodes ?

Comment: When you read a file using Spark, it will return the RDD with multiple partitions based on file size, block size etc.. not multiple RDDs and when you save this RDD for each and every partition there will be a separate part file.

Comment: The location of all the files will be same in that case. e.g. rdd.saveAsTextfile(<s3-path>). I need to save all part files in separate location so that I can send all these individual s3 paths to different jobs for example 10 s3 locations to 10 separate jobs

Comment: You may want to explore forEachPartition http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/how-to-split-RDD-by-key-and-save-to-different-path-td11887.html#a11983